# Pulling down list of files from Sharepoint and loading the files on my local machine

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have about 136K files I need to download from my SharePoint site so I can create an MD5 has for the files and record the has values in a local database.  I am using the following code below to grab the list of files:

```
 public static List<SP.ListItem> GetAllDocumentsInaLibrary()
    {
        List<SP.ListItem> items = new List<SP.ListItem>();
        string siteURL = @"[URL to SharePoint]";
        using (var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL))
        {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.Lists);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            int i = 0;
            SP.List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ArchivedData");
            SP.ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
            int rowLimit = 100;
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                  <Query>
                                    <OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy>
                                  </Query>
                                  <ViewFields>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ID' />
                                  </ViewFields>
                                  <RowLimit Page='TRUE'>" + rowLimit + "</RowLimit></View>";
            do
            {
                SP.ListItemCollection listItems = null;
                camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
                listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                ctx.Load(listItems);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                i += 100;
                position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                items.AddRange(listItems.ToList());
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            while (position != null);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Here is the calling line for this code:

```
List<SP.ListItem> item = GetAllDocumentsInaLibrary();
```

This works just fine.  Now I want to iterate this list and download the files, to local location so I can create the MD5 hash of the file, and this is where I am stuck.  I used this code below to pull 10 files at a time and it worked, but now, I want to iterate the whole list generated from the GetAllDocumentsInaLibrary method to do this.

```
 SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url);
        SP.Web oWebSite = ctx.Web;
        SP.List list = oWebSite.Lists.GetByTitle("ArchivedData");


            foreach (SP.ListItem listitem in item)
            {
                ctx.Load(listitem, i => i.File);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                var fileRef = listitem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                var fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef);
                var fileName = @"c:\downloads\" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listitem.File.Title) ? listitem.File.Name : listitem.File.Title);
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
```

When I try to do this, I get an error on the ctx.Load(Listitem, i => i.File) line:

> Additional information: The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is as the error says. The generic list of items (`item`) you generated refer to a different context than the one in the `foreach (SP.ListItem listitem in item)`. Hence the error. You need to have the same context for both. That said, you should probably use a `parallel.foreach` loop if you have that many files. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981744/getting-stackoverflow-exception-with-parallel-for-each-is-this-due-to-thread-s

Comment: Thanks.  I think I got around this.  I am wrapping this loop into parallel.foreach, but I am not seeing much of an increase at all.  Still working through that.